# ParaView shows displacement as color

Tags: visualization, vtk, paraview, finite-element-analysis

In my current "Partial Differential Equations" lecture we write software to solve PDEs numerically. In the process we had to approximate a function `f` by a continuous, piecewise linear function. Our software has the capabilities to export the approximation as `.vtu`-file.
We were asked to plot it with ParaView, but when I open the `.vtu`-file and make the object visible it's just a coloured plane.

The different colours display the different function values, but it would be a lot nicer to displace the plane according to its colouring (e.g. to display the function). Shouldn't this be the case automatically?

Is the `.vtu` file broken/am I doing something wrong with the import or is this the default ParaView behaviour and I need to put in more work to display the function?

**Example:** This is what I see

[image: The functor is displayed as a coloured plane]

for this `.vtu`-file: https://pastebin.com/UQuiTjA5

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Warp By Scalar** function to warp your plane according to the data array. While it might be nice to warp by scalar array for your use case, there are plenty of use cases where one indeed wants a plane to be a plane and not warp by a scalar automatically.

Another thing you could do is apply the warp in your code that generates the VTU file by saving the Gamma function as the z value of each point in the plane (or a scaled version of the Gamma function).